Sudden shift of my automatic car from 5th to 3rd gear
I have Maruti Suzuki Swift VXI 2018 automatic car in India.
Two things happen:
When I increase the speed towards 5th gear, the gear suddenly shifts to lower gear (2nd or 3rd gear).  What could be the issue?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

I'd suggest, there's no issue. If you press on the accelerator pedal enough, the transmission will downshift to lower gears. This brings the engine into a greater torque range and allows the vehicle to accelerate faster. Downshifting is dependent upon many factors, such as which gear the transmission is in, how much stress is being put on the vehicle (ie: flat surface, incline, decline), and how much you press the go pedal. All of these factors are electronically built into tables in your Powertrain/Transmission Control Module (PCM or TCM) and will determine which gear it will put the transmission in, thus why it may not seem consistent when downshifting.
